# Cache slow query with WordPress object cache

Tags: mysql, caching, redis

I use Sphere post views plugin but overloading mysql server with 600% CPU load.
Is there any way that I could cache the slow query with Redis Object cache that I use on my WP site?

here is the query.

```
Creating sort index | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, COALESCE(spvr.pageviews, 0) AS post_views
FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN (
SELECT SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews, postid FROM wp_popularpostssummary WHERE view_date >= '2023-08-30' GROUP BY postid
) spvr ON spvr.postid = wp_posts.ID
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))



ORDER BY post_views DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Is there any way that I could optimize that?

Thank you

I have used that function to reduce the queries from the plugin.

```
/*******Query change - Hook the callback function to the 'posts_fields' filter ******/
function modify_posts_fields($fields, $query) {

// include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';

// //check for plugin using plugin name
// if ( !is_plugin_active( 'sphere-post-views/sphere-post-views.php' ) ) {
// return $fields;
// }

global $wpdb;
// query we want to modify
if (!$query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && $query->spv_query && is_front_page()) {
$fields = $wpdb->prefix . 'http://posts.ID'.','.$wpdb->prefix . 'http://posts.post_title'.',LEFT('.$wpdb->prefix . 'http://posts.post_content, 200) AS post_content'.','.$wpdb->prefix . 'http://posts.post_name'.','.$wpdb->prefix . 'http://posts.post_date';
}
return $fields;
}
add_filter('posts_fields', 'modify_posts_fields', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results from EXPLAIN (your query); for analysis.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

May be try change the query process

```
SELECT wp_posts_published.*, pageviews AS post_views
FROM 
(
  SELECT wp_posts.*
  FROM wp_posts
  WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
) wp_posts_published
LEFT JOIN 
(  
  SELECT postid, SUM(IFNULL(pageviews,0)) AS pageviews
  FROM wp_popularpostssummary
  WHERE view_date >= '2023-08-30' 
  GROUP BY postid
 ) spvr
ON spvr.postid = wp_posts_published.ID 
ORDER BY spvr.pageviews DESC, wp_posts_published.post_date DESC
```